# Fabric.js right mouse click

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to receive right click mouse events on a Fabric.js canvas?

The following code works only with left click:

```
canvas.observe('mouse:down', function(){console.log('mouse down'));
```

Comment: Just watch for click event on canvas (not via fabric but using DOM methods), then check that it's right click and not left.

Comment: For latest versions (tested in Fabric 2.7.0) you simply need to enable these events in the canvas configuration. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614126/1697459)

Answer (score 27):

**NOTE:** *Most answers above are outdated; this answer applies to the latest Fabric version 2.7.0*

---

### Simply enable firing right/middle click events for your Fabric canvas

The config for firing right click and middle click events in the canvas can be found [here for `fireRightClick`](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/canvas.class.js#L327) and [here for `fireMiddleClick`](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/canvas.class.js#L335) and are set to `false` by default. This means right and middle click events are by default disabled.
The parameter `stopContextMenu` for stopping context menu to show up on the canvas when right clicking can be found [here](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/canvas.class.js#L319)

You can enable these simply by setting the values when creating your canvas:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  height: height,
  width: width,
  fireRightClick: true,  // <-- enable firing of right click events
  fireMiddleClick: true, // <-- enable firing of middle click events
  stopContextMenu: true, // <--  prevent context menu from showing
});
```

Now your `mousedown` event will fire for all clicks and you can distinguish them by using the button identifier on the event:

### For canvas:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', (event) => {
    if(event.button === 1) {
        console.log("left click");
    }
    if(event.button === 2) {
        console.log("middle click");
    }
    if(event.button === 3) {
        console.log("right click");
    }
}
```

### For objects:

```
object.on('mousedown', (event) => {
    if(event.button === 1) {
        console.log("left click");
    }
    if(event.button === 2) {
        console.log("middle click");
    }
    if(event.button === 3) {
        console.log("right click");
    }
}
```

---

When clicking on objects you can reach the "real" mouse dom event through event.e:

```
if(event.button === 3){
  console.log(event.e);
}
```

Comment: preventing the context menu doesn't work for me. What am I missing? both IE and Chrome show a context menu on canvas right click (console log works fine).

Comment: @ps0604 Are you sure you are calling `preventDefault()` on the DOM event (`event.e`). You can double check which object is the DOM event by logging it to the console.

Comment: The preventDefault isn't working for me either. using event.e.preventDefault gives "cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined." Printing 'element' to the log shows that it is a MouseEvent. printing 'element.e' shows undefined. So I changed your code to event.preventDefault(); but the popup still occurs. What am I missing?

Comment: If you get that error message and output in console, it means the event variable is the DOM event. What happens if you add both `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` I will try once in a fiddle. What version of canvas.js are you using?

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing the result. I also had to renumber the buttons to be correct.. I had been using 2.4.6, but switched to 2.7.0 when I saw this post. Both result in the same action: https://jsfiddle.net/morrowsend/qzr1s2a7/5/

Comment: @morrows_end I updated my answer. Check an updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7km3nfL9/

Comment: oh, duh. I forgot to stopContextMenu. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @morrows_end, I added that in my update so not your fault. You can now skip all the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` logic. It apparently only works for objects, not for the canvas. I also missed it at first, and it is much easier :D

Comment: The `event.button` codes above are wrong - they go from 0 to 2, not 1 to 3, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events#determining_button_states

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented right click by extending the fabric.Canvas class. Take a look [here](https://github.com/mazong1123/fabric.ext/blob/master/fabricext/scripts/fabric.canvasex.js#L63) the `_onMouseDown` method.

Basically the right mouse down event for an object was disabled in fabricjs by default.

Comment: Hi, that is fine but I still don't understand. What will happen on right click if i use this extended _onMouseDown event in your library. Wanted behavior in the context of the question is - if we have a plugin for context menu, we want to override default behavior on this.canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => someFunc(e));
and trigger function from the plugin to show the context menu.
Meanwhile on right click the default browser context menu should be not present. That should be responsibility of the plugin itself, but just wonder should we do anything else in addition with fabricJs

Comment: Personally i use angular 6 and $('#my_canvas').bind('contextmenu') does't work for me. I prefer "cleanly" extending event and objects in typescript way (OOP way).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle right clicks (on canvas or its objects), then set context menu listener on upper-canvas element. Using canvas method findTarget you can check if any target was clicked and if so, you can check type of the target.

```
let scope = this;
jQuery(".upper-canvas").on('contextmenu', function (options: any) {
    let target: any = scope.canvas.findTarget(options, false);
    if (target) {
        let type: string = target.type;
        if (type === "group") {
            console.log('right click on group');
        } else {
            scope.canvas.setActiveObject(target);
            console.log('right click on target, type: ' + type);
        }
    } else {
        scope.canvas.discardActiveObject();
        scope.canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        scope.canvas.renderAll();
        console.log('right click on canvas');
    }
    options.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: Awesome, with a little modification, remove `discardActiveGroup` and removing the type distinction between "group" and "aciveSelection".

Answer (score 3):

The way I did this was to listen for a right click event across the entire canvas and match up the x,y coordinates of the click event to the object which is currently sitting at the given location. This solution feels a little like a hack but hey, it works!

```
$('#my_canvas').bind('contextmenu', function (env) {
    var x = env.offsetX;
    var y = env.offsetY;
    $.each (canvas._objects, function(i, e) {
        // e.left and e.top are the middle of the object use some "math" to find the outer edges
        var d = e.width / 2;
        var h = e.height / 2;
        if (x >= (e.left - d) && x <= (e.left+d)) {
            if(y >= (e.top - h) && y <= (e.top+h)) {
                console.log("clicked canvas obj #"+i);
                //TODO show custom menu at x, y
                return false; //in case the icons are stacked only take action on one.
            }
        }
    });
    return false; //stops the event propigation
});
```

Comment: @jsbeckr it works in the sense that it finds the first canvas object that matches those coordinates and then stops. You could get smarter and build up a list of objects at that x/y location and then pick one of them to take action on (e.g. the one at the highest z-index?)

Comment: Yep I did that. And I realized that your solution doesn't consider scaled objects. Which was quite frustrating... :D But it's quite easy to fix that: `var d = e.width * e.scaleX / 2;` and `var h = e.height * e.scaleY / 2;`

Comment: @jsbeckr what about rotated objects ? did you managed to make a fix for that too ?

Comment: @Bor691 Sorry I didn't need that. :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did, which makes use of some built-in fabric object detection code:

```
$('.upper-canvas').bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    var objectFound = false;
    var clickPoint = new fabric.Point(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);

    e.preventDefault();

    canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
        if (!objectFound && obj.containsPoint(clickPoint)) {
            objectFound = true;
            //TODO: whatever you want with the object
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi! for some reason when clicking back on the canvas the menu does not disappear. Any ideas?