# Contextmenu on the objects in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, contextmenu, fabricjs

Can you please help me in creating a context menu on the fabric object. I have googled a lot but couldn't find exact solution. I have created two objects as below on the fabric. How can i bind a context menu to the fabric object?
Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sigh...how hard did you really look? :-( I googled "fabricJS context menu" and [this relevant Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108310/fabric-js-right-mouse-click)  on creating a FabricJS context menu was right on top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabric.js right mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108310/fabric-js-right-mouse-click)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [contextMenu.js](https://github.com/s-yadav/contextMenu.js), this should get you started:

```
function contextMenu () {
    var ctxTarget = null;

    var menu = [{
        name: 'Select Object',
        img: '',
        title: 'Select Object',
        fun: function (o, jqEvent) {
            canvas.setActiveObject(ctxTarget);
            console.log(ctxTarget);
        }
    }];

    $('.upper-canvas').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctxTarget = canvas.findTarget(e.originalEvent);
    });

    $('.upper-canvas').contextMenu(menu, {
        triggerOn: 'contextmenu',
        closeOnClick: true,
    });
}
```